# Fixed Header Blocks Scrolling through fullPage.js Sections with "scrollOverflow: true"

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

A fixed header on my website blocks scrolling, when hovering, through sections when set `scrollOverflow: true`.

When fixed header is not hovered scrolling through all sections works fine.

How can I achieve the same browsing through sections, when hovering fixed header?

Isolated Reproduction:
https://jsfiddle.net/o5Lcpemw/1/

Steps to reproduce it:

1. Hover fixed red header
2. Try to scroll through blue, grey and green sections

MacOS High Sierra, latest Chrome Release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stop allowing the header to respond to mouse events by setting the element's [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) value to none:

```
#header {
  ...
  pointer-events: none;

}
```

Comment: But then the links in the header won't work anymore. Setting the links to pointer-events: all; prevents still scrolling when hovering the link on the fixed header. I'm looking for a cleaner solution. Any ideas?

Comment: @MathiasNösel Unless there is something in the docs for fullpage.js that specifies otherwise I'm guessing that you would need to use some form of javascript that triggers when the header is over a scrollable section of the page and the user is scrolling and when this state is present, continue scrolling the section. I can't think of a pure CSS solution and I've never used fullpage.js I'm afraid.